# Rails: Scoped ID in addition to primary id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope

Say that I have many blogs, and each blog `has_many` posts.  These are stored in 2 tables ("blogs" and "posts").  Is it possible to add an additional column (e.g. scoped_id) to the blog table which stores an ID, scoped by the blog.

Example

```
 Blog: 1
  - Posts
    - id: 1, scoped_id: 1
    - id: 2, scoped_id: 2
    - id: 3, scoped_id: 3
 Blog: 2
  - Posts
    - id: 4, scoped_id: 1
    - id: 5, scoped_id: 2
    - id: 6, scoped_id: 3
```

I know that counter_cache can keep track of the number of posts scoped by the parent blog.  However, I don't want the `scoped_id` to decrement if a post is destroyed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet would be to keep the last used ID on the blog, and populate it via:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  …
  before_create :populate_scoped_id

  def populate_scoped_id
    blog.increment!(:latest_scoped_post_id)
    self[:scoped_id] = blog.latest_scoped_post_id
  end
  …
end
```

or some jazz like that.

If the save fails, the counter will not be incremented, because it's all in a whopping great transaction (it's, like, totally enterprise).

Comment: This code is vulnerable to a race condition that can result in two or more blog entries having the same scoped_id when the server handles two requests concurrently. For example, consider the following sequence: (1) Request A reads latest_scoped_post_id x, (2) Request B reads the same latest_scoped_post_id x, (3) Request A sets scoped_id to x + 1, (4) Request B sets scoped_id to x + 1 (same as request A).

Comment: You might expect that being in a transaction would protect against race conditions like this, but it won't, unless you set the transaction isolation level unusually high (likely a bad idea for performance reasonse).

Answer (score 1):

yes you can definitely add another column, and if it's me, i would do a **before_save** callback to save the **scoped_id** if it's a **new_record?**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  before_save :populate_scoped_id

  def populate_scoped_id
    assign_the_scoped_id_method if self.new_record?
  end
  ...
end
```

hope it helps =)

Comment: Thanks, but how would you ensure that the same scoped_id is never repeated for the parent blog?

Comment: i would take the largest scoped_id and increment it by 1 (replace assign_the_scoped_id_method):
    self.scoped_id = Post.maximum(:scoped_id) + 1

Comment: Don't forget to add an unique index in your database: add_index :posts, [:id, :scoped_id], :unique => true. Otherwise there could (at least in theory) be two simultaneous requests and you could end up with the same scoped_id twice.

Comment: yeah to prevent race conditions ;-) always the devil

Comment: The race condition is *not* only theoretical, I can tell you from experience :-).